# Github secret token verification

Tags: go, cryptography

I'm making a little API using Go. I would like to be able to handle Github webhooks with secret token. I set up the secret on my webhook Github which is "azerty".

Now I try to verify that the incoming webhook has the correct secret token. I've read Github documentation which say the algorithm use HMAC with SHA1. But I can't verify the secret from the incoming Github webhook ...

```
func IsValidSignature(r *http.Request, key string) bool {
    // KEY => azerty

    gotHash := strings.SplitN(r.Header.Get("X-Hub-Signature"), "=", 2)
    if gotHash[0] != "sha1" {
        return false
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cannot read the request body: %s\n", err)
        return false
    }

    hash := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(key))
    if _, err := hash.Write(b); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Cannot compute the HMAC for request: %s\n", err)
        return false
    }

    expectedHash := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
    log.Println("EXPECTED HASH:", expectedHash)
    log.Println("GOT HASH:", gotHash[1])
    return gotHash[1] == expectedHash
}
EXPECTED HASH: 10972179a3b0efc337f79ec41847062bc598bb04
GOT HASH: 36de72e0d386e36e2c7b034c85cd3b3889594992
```

To test, I copy the payload of the Github webhook in Postman with the right headers. I don't know why I get two different hash ... I've checked my key is non-empty with the correct value and my body is non-empty too.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure body is intact after copy? Perhaps some trailing `\n` added and it screws it all. Also, use `hmac.Equal` and `hash.Write()` never returns errors.

Comment: I try to serve my local server with Ngrok and you are right, my copy/paste should had hidden characters ... Now my two hashes are equal. Feel free to post your answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I copy the payload of the Github webhook in Postman with the right header.
>
> I've checked my key is non-empty with the correct value and my body is non-empty too.

The crypto is correct, except few minor issues. Obviously your body does not match the same body you have got from Github. Could be formatting, trailing newlines, etc. It must exactly byte-to-byte match the original body.

If this code works with Github and does not work with copy in Postman just replace `X-Hub-Signature` in your fixture with that "wrong" hash.

Some extras:

- Use `hmac.Equal` for secure comparison
- `hash.Write` never returns errors

Comment: In my case copy-paste added additional new line characters. I removed all formatting chars and passed pure json.